# SQL Server Visual Studio SSIS Versioning

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Something similar to my problem has been posted before but not quite like this. I have Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. I develop packages with this and deploy the project to SQL Server 12.0.4100.01. The packages run fine. Then I try to deploy from the ispac and I get the error:

> There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: 
>       The Script Task **redacted** uses version 14.0 script that is not supported
>        in this release of Integration Services. To run the package, use the Script
>        Task to create a new VSTA script. In most cases, scripts are converted 
>       automatically to use a supported version, when you open a SQL Server 
>        Integration Services package in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Integration 
>       Services.
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML
>               (XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)

I checked the xml in Visual Studio and unpacked the ispac to compare the code in each and all the versioning code is the same. Apparently there is an upgrade/downgrade operation happening when deploying from Visual Studio but doesn't happen when deploying from the ispac. Is there a way to create an ispac that is version compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the project property TargetServerVersion : SQL Server 2012/2014/2016

[image]

The script language will be changed automatically to Microsoft Visual c# 2010/2012/2015.

**Note**: First copy code from the script task and save it.

[image]

Comment: I tried that before I posted the question; it doesn't solve the problem. Deploying from VS is no problem but deploying from the generated ispac is a problem with the versioning. Apparently VS does some sort of version correction when deployment happens. With the ispac not being in VS, that doesn't happen and the package fails at the script task because of version incompatibility.